# 100% Div Height of Parent?

Tags: css, styling

I am drastically trying to find way to make a div 100% height of it's parent. Only trick is that the parents height is going to be dynamic.

Any ideas on this? I cannot find a solution anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there isn't a clean solution...they're all hacks. see [abcoder](https://web.archive.org/web/20111204163859/http://abcoder.com/css/css-equal-height-columns)

You can use javascript/jquery,

```
$(function () {
    var maxheight = Math.max.apply(null,$('.col').map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }));
    $('.col').height(maxheight);
});
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/4gLWB/) -- uses `box-sizing` so that I could put some padding on the columns, but isn't strictly necessary.

Or you can wrap all your divs in another div, and then use a vertically-tiled background on the containing div to give the appearance that they're separate columns, even though the inner divs don't extend all the way down.

Tables or emulated tables (using CSS) will also work.

I *think* there may be some solutions involving CSS3 these days, however. This answer is from 2011, so use your judgement.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been looking around and finding hacks, I know this is a hack but it's the best I've come across.

Comment: Its a shame to see this answer is merely a link with no code or explanation.

Comment: This is why links as answers are low quality.

Comment: Yes yes, I'm sorry guys. I've updated the link to way back machine and added some code. Vicious with the downvotes.

Comment: It's nothing personal, you edited, I reverted my vote. Downvotes aren't vicious :P

Comment: You gave me less than an hour to get my shit together :p I try not to do link-only answers anymore...they really do suck.

Comment: Yep nothing personal either. Sadly I am sticking with the down vote as  I favour the hacky css over the javascript solution.

Comment: @mikedidthis: Preference is one thing, but I usually reserve downvotes for things that outright don't work or are plain wrong. Oh well, it's up to you.

Comment: I'm kind of curious how the 2 of you caught this so quickly... I got notified because it's my answer, but...

Comment: @Mark It was a mix of preference and question not being tagged with javascript / jQuery. Anyway I reverted the downvote as the answer has been expanded on and should help others, good job!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, it depends.

A nice easy way to do it (at least in my opinion) is using conflicting absolute positioning:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Accounts for padding and you can code in margins. Downside is that it removes the element from the flow of the page, so you'll have to go around that. Also, support is IE7+.

Another way to do it (also IE7+) is using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`.

```
#parent {
    display: table;
}
#parent div {
    display: table-cell; /* To make all children act as table-cells */
}
```